# How to respond when someone say "I hope it helps"

Tags: phrase-request, politeness, spoken-english

We are given an assignment, and my foreigner seatmate helped me to answer one question and he added "I hope it helps"

I am not sure what to respond, out of my to speak in English I responded thank you, need any help on how to respond to these.

Comment: A simple "thank you" is sufficient.

Comment: Would you like to know how to better word your question? It is perfectly understandable, however, it is not correct English. You are doing so well with your studies that I would like to help. This is not meant to be unkind in any way.

Comment: This is too open-ended, plus it's more about *manners* than learning English. You might just give your friend a [winning smile](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/winning%20smile), for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use these answers:

> I am sure it will

Or

> I hope so too

"Thank you" is totally acceptable

Comment: *I hope so too* is rather a brusque answer that I wouldn't recommend for the type of dialog explained in the OP.

Comment: I thought he asked for answers for a more general context
I agree that it rather a brusque answer when you're talking to a seatmate